# Extending etale morphisms

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-covers

Let $Y$ be an affine, integral, Gorenstein surface. Let $y \in Y$ be a closed point such that there exists a finite, etale morphism $f: X \to Y\backslash \{y\}$ from an integral variety $X$ to the open subvariety $Y \backslash y$. Does there exist an integeral variety $\overline{X}$ containing $X$ as an open dense subscheme and a finite morphism $\overline{f}: \overline{X} \to Y$ restricting to $f$ over $X$ such that the fiber over $y$ consists of exactly one closed point (not necessarily reduced)?

Comment: Yes: first choose any finite morphism $g:Z \to Y$ extending $f$ with $Z$ integral (e.g., by normalizing $Y$ in $X$), and then construct $\overline{X}$ by crushing the finite closed subscheme $g^{-1}(y) \subset Z$ to a single point (so take a suitable fibre product at the level of rings).

Comment: @Anonymous Thank you. Could you put this in the answer. Especially, could you elaborate a little (or give reference) for what you mean by "crushing". Is it something like blowing down? If so, why does a "crushing" always exist? I think the answer lies in what you say "suitable fibre product at the level of rings", but this statement is not clear to me.

Comment: For the existence of the crushing (also called "pinching", or Ferrand pushout) see [this paper](http://www.numdam.org/item/BSMF_2003__131_4_553_0/), or [this section](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07RS) of the Stacks Project.

Comment: In this case the construction is very simple: take $g$ as in Anonymous's comment. Then $\ol{X}=\mathrm{Spec}(\mathscr{A}))$ where $\mathscr{A}\subset g_*\mathscr{O}_Z$ is the subalgebra of sections whose restriction on $g^{-1}(y)$ is constant (i.e. comes from $\kappa(y)$).

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly and Anonymous; Thank you for the answer